# How to make maven find Resource Leaks like eclipse does

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins, memory-leaks

So we use Jenkins and Maven for our automated builds and the B&R group wants to add a way to break the build if someone checks in code that doesn't close classes like Readers, Writers, etc... I have searched far and wide, but it seems that the only thing that finds these Resource Leaks well is the eclipse compiler. Does anyone know of a Maven plugin that can do the same thing?

Comment: SonarQube or Findbugs might have rules to check for things like this.